# Get latest record by JOIN TABLE with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I was able to get latest purchased (`package_id`) of client `c001` using this query (without adding date condition).

```
SELECT  s1.date, s1.client_id, s1.package_id 
FROM purchaseHistory s1 
LEFT JOIN purchaseHistory s2 ON s1.date < s2.date 
                            AND s1.client_id = s2.client_id
WHERE  s1.released = '1'
  AND s1.verified = '1'
  AND s2.client_id IS NULL
  AND s1.client_id = c001
```

Currently I was expecting to get latest purchased before date (`2021-10-26 23:59:59`). The following code is my query.

```
SELECT  s1.date, s1.client_id, s1.package_id 
FROM purchaseHistory s1 
LEFT JOIN purchaseHistory s2 ON s1.date < s2.date 
                            AND s1.client_id=s2.client_id 
                            AND s1.date <= 2021-10-26 23:59:59 
WHERE  s1.released = '1'
  AND s1.verified = '1'
  AND s2.client_id IS NULL
  AND s1.client_id = c001
```

Instead it returned all purchased (`package_id`) and ignore condition (`s1.date <= 2021-10-26 23:59:59`)

Comment: *`AND 's1.date <= 2021-10-26 23:59:59' `* Look at quote chars position... *`AND s1.client_id = c001`* Does `c001` is a column in some table? or you loose quote chars?

Comment: You can try adding an "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1" into your query

Answer (score 0):

```
date(s1.date)<=CURDATE()
```

This is if you are working on MySQL and want to get the records before or at the current date.